# How to check that a delete / update operation completed successfully when using a stored procedure?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, tableadapter

Say we have stored procedure(s) performing simple operations like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddNewAuthorReturnID]
(   
    @Author_Name VARCHAR(MAX),
    @Author_ID int OUTPUT
)
AS
    SET NOCOUNT OFF;
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO AUTHORS (@Author_Name)
    VALUES (@Author_Name)
    SET @Author_ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    
    SELECT @Author_ID
 END
```

In the above procedure, the returned id is an indication of successful operation.

Consider the equivalent with `DELETE`.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[DeleteAuthor]
(       
    @Author_ID int 
)
AS
    SET NOCOUNT OFF;
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM AUTHORS 
    WHERE
    (Author_ID = @Author_ID)
END
```

- How can we know the operation was
  successful and the `AUTHORS` record was
  succesfully removed if we use the above
  procedure ?
- With an update operation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could select @@rowcount

It will show you the rows affected.

e.g

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[DeleteAuthor]
(       
    @Author_ID int 
)
AS
    SET NOCOUNT OFF;
BEGIN
 DELETE FROM AUTHORS 
 WHERE
 (Author_ID = @Author_ID)
 SELECT @@ROWCOUNT 
END
```

This can be applied to update too.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateAuthor]
(       
    @Author_ID int 
)
AS
    SET NOCOUNT OFF;
BEGIN
 UPDATE AUTHORS 
    SET AuthorName = 'John'
 WHERE
 (Author_ID = @Author_ID)
 SELECT @@ROWCOUNT 
END
```

Alternatively you could use @@Error and raise an error id @@rowcount > 1 (if you only wanted to update one row).

e.g

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[DeleteAuthor]
(       
    @Author_ID int 
)
AS
    SET NOCOUNT OFF;
BEGIN
 DELETE FROM AUTHORS 
 WHERE
 (Author_ID = @Author_ID)

 IF @@ROWCOUNT <>1
 BEGIN
  RAISERROR ('An error occured',10,1)
  RETURN -1
 END
END
```

As Giorgi says this will be returned as a returncode.

Comment: @John, What if the statement did not affect any rows but no error has occurred?

Comment: @asdi, you can use @@ROWCOUNT in the same way with update operation but I do not recommend using it because if the stored procedure executes without error but no rows are affected it will return 0

Comment: What is the better approach then ? should we make a check after the operation than record is still there or not ?

Comment: @asdi, return @@ERROR from you stored procedure.

Answer (score 3):

You can to return `@@ROWCOUNT` to determine if your last statement affected any record.

Comment: @Rubens, What if the statement did not affect any rows but no error has occurred?

Comment: You're right, @Giorgi but I would to expect update/delete statements to affect records on online applications; bottom line is: depends on what OP want to do

Answer (score 1):

You can return value from stored procedure using return statement. The `@@ERROR` variable is equal to zero if there was no error.

[@@ERROR](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188790.aspx)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[DeleteAuthor]
(       
    @Author_ID int 
)
AS
    SET NOCOUNT OFF;
BEGIN
 DELETE FROM AUTHORS 
 WHERE
 (Author_ID = @Author_ID)

 Return @@ERROR

END
```

Comment: This returns if there is no error but what if the user was expecting to delete a record and it wasn't there?

Comment: This is not a good suggestion because even if no rows where found to be deleted, `@@ERROR` is still equal to `0`. `@@ERROR` will only be different from `0` if something horrendous went wrong with the server or the query itself, like a `DEADLOCK` or `TIMEOUT` or bad syntax or just when an exception is thrown.